# List woocommerce products side by side in two containers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wrote this PHP code to list woocommerce products by a specific category. I have two div containers in my page now I would like to get these products one by one for each container. The code lists all products into container1 as it should. But I'm stuck with modifying the code to get the products to list side by side for each container. If my question is not clear, this is what I simply meant.

**What this code does,**

```
container1        container2

product1          empty
product2
product3
product4
```

**What I want to do is this,**

```
container1        container2

product1          product2
product3          product4
```

**The code is**

```
<?php

$args = array( 'category' => array( 'shirts' ), );

$productlist = wc_get_products( $args );

// List products for container one

echo '<div class="container1>'

echo '<ul class="product-list-wrap">';

// loop through the product list
foreach ($productlist as $product) {

$productid = $product->get_id(); // get individual product id
$custom_field = get_field( 'custom_field', $productid ); // get the custom field

echo '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">
<li class="product-name">'.$product->get_title().'<span class="custom">'.$custom_field.'</span>'.'</li>
</a>';
}

echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';

// List products for container two

echo '<div class="container2>'

echo '<ul class="product-list-wrap">';

content

echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';

?>
```

**HTML output**

```
<div class="container1">

    <ul class="product-list-wrap">

        <a href="http://localhost/project1/product/product-1/">
        <li class="product-name">Product 1<span class="custom">custom output</span></li>
        </a>

        <a href="http://localhost/project1/product/product-2/">
        <li class="product-name">Product 1<span class="custom">custom output</span></li>
        </a>

        <a href="http://localhost/project1/product/product-3/">
        <li class="product-name">Product 1<span class="custom">custom output</span></li>
        </a>

        <a href="http://localhost/project1/product/product-4/">
        <li class="product-name">Product 1<span class="custom">custom output</span></li>
        </a>

    </ul>                            

</div>

<div class="container2">

    <ul class="product-list-wrap">

    content

    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Please also provide the rendered html output.

Comment: @MikeAron html output is added as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$productList1 = array();
$productList2 = array();

foreach( $productlist as $key=>$product ) {
    if( $key % 2 == 0 ) {
        // even key (0, 2, 4, ...)
        array_push( $productList1, $product );
    }
    else {
        // odd key (1, 3, 5, ...)
        array_push( $productList2, $product );
    }
}
```

And then use $productList1 for the first container loop and $productList2 for the second container loop.

Comment: You was faster then me :)

Comment: @sparkinglabs awesome :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Put all your products in 1 array
$container_data = array();

foreach ($productlist as $product) {

$productid = $product->get_id(); // get individual product id
$custom_field = get_field( 'custom_field', $productid ); // get the custom field

// fill the array
$container_data[] = '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">
<li class="product-name">'.$product->get_title().'<span class="custom">'.$custom_field.'</span>'.'</li>
</a>';

}

// Split your array
list($container_1, $container_2) = array_chunk($container_data, ceil(count($container_data) / 2));

// You have now 2 arrays
// $container_1
// $container_2

// Now loop again

echo '<div class="container1>';

echo '<ul class="product-list-wrap">';

foreach ($container_1 as $product) {
echo $product;
}

echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';

// Now loop again

echo '<div class="container2>';

echo '<ul class="product-list-wrap">';

foreach ($container_2 as $product) {
echo $product;
}

echo '</ul>';

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I have already tried the solution by @Dominik and it works. But many thanks to you anyway :)

Comment: Its the same logic.